# How to refer to an array without creating a new one?

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to refer to my USERS list in a form without having to create a new instance of the class the list is stored in as it creates a new list.

The LoginHandler class where the list is created and is added to.

```
namespace BG
{
    public class LoginHandler
    {
         public List<User> users = new List<User>();

         public LoginHandler()
         {
            users = new List<User>();
         }
```

The form will consist of a for loop which loops to the count of items in the list so i need to refer back to it but do not want to have to create a new instance of class its in because that makes a new list which i do not want.

Comment: one of the two `new List<User>()`is redundant.

Comment: make your users list static

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking. What is the bigger picture here? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: It it not quite clear what your problem is and what are you trying to achieve. Probably you need to make `users` static or maybe entire `LoginHandler` should be static class. Or maybe your LoginHelper should implement single-instance pattern. It's hard to say more based on information you've submitted.

Comment: static will work, but throwing static everywhere is going to cause problem

Comment: what about passing the users list as a parameter to the constructor ?

Comment: I've made it static and this error comes up now, Error 10 Member 'BG.LoginHandler.users' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is a property that returns a reference to a IEnumerable object.

```
public class LoginHandler
{
    private List<User> users = new List<User>();
    public IEnumerable<User> Users { get { return users; } }
}
```

Then you can access the property without creating a copy or exposing the internal data members.

```
LoginHandler handler = new LoginHandler();
foreach (var user in handler.Users)
{
}
```